# What's the limit of stylesheets on a page for modern browsers [2015]?

Tags: html, css

I tried to find some info about the limit of stylesheets on a page per browser but it doesn't seem to be documented too well. Older browsers were limited to 32 stylesheets per page, what about current chrome etc.?

Comment: That is specific to Internet Explorer. And only <=IE9 as far as I can tell. Any modern browser should not impose an insane restriction like that given that HTTP2 allows for async asset downloading

Comment: define "new", this could be answered if you provide some specific browsers and version numbers

Comment: As @RGraham already said, the number of max. 32 stylesheets on a page was a thing in older IE mainly; I don’t know of any other browser that ever had such a low limit. So unless you are doing something extremely out of the ordinary (like constantly appending new stylesheets to a document via JS), you should be fine in any “modern” browser with any amount of stylesheets that could be considered reasonable and practical.

Comment: @RGraham Probably off topic, but why would 32 stylesheets on a page be "an insane restriction"? Personally, when someone asked here on SO about a problem on a website, and I see the website contains more than 15 or 20 stylesheets, I give up. I shiver when I think of websites with 65535 stylesheets.